# issue with loading React static files from NGINX web server

Tags: nginx, pm2, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

NGINX web server takes about 3 minutes to load a React static file of about 3MB. and that slow download the performance of load the application

I have tried zipping the static file on my React file

this is my current configuration in NGINX

```
upstream app1{
    # Use ip_hash algo for session affinity
    least_conn;
    server 192.168.1.7:3000;
    server 192.168.3.7:3000;
}
location /app1 {
        # Force timeouts if the backend dies
        #proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

        # Set timeouts
        proxy_connect_timeout  3600;
        proxy_send_timeout     3600;
        proxy_read_timeout     3600;
        send_timeout           3600;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://app1/;

        proxy_buffering         off;
    }
location ~* ^/static {
        proxy_pass https://app1$request_uri;
        proxy_buffering         off;
    }
location ~ ^/build {
        proxy_pass https://app1$request_uri;
    }
```

I want to be able to serve the static content within the NGINX sever without haven't fetch from the application server. also I want to be able to compress the file to the minimum size like 10 kilobyte.

Comment: Go to developer tools(Press F12) for chrome --> Audits tab --> click on 'Run audits'. This will tell you what could be improved for your applcation. Example you could add gzip compression from nginx but more ideas could be inferred based on your code that is why lighthouse is the way to go.

Comment: thanks chugh, I'll try that out